# Expressing 'our' for objects belonging to our apartment

Tags: грамматика

Should I write 
Два балкона находятся у нас в квартире or 
Два балкона находятся в нашем квартире
I am trying to write that we have two balconies on our flat.

Comment: Квартира is feminine so нашей, not нашем.

Comment: a balcony cannot obtain (**находиться**) in(side) an apartment, because after all it's situated outside of it, so in the worst case one may say **Наша квартира имеет два балкона** as in English, but i cosign idiomatic variants suggested by Sandra

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка **obtain (находиться)** I know it's not relevant to the question but that's a weird usage of 'obtain'. :) What dictionary gave you that?

Comment: @tum_ i know that to obtain is a higher register synonym of to exist, and i'm not aware of a good English equivalent to the Russian находиться in this context, that's why i opted for it, in case you are, please share

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка (with a risk to get banned for an unrelated chat) "Два балкона находятся у нас в квартире" - тут сложно говорить о контексте, так как по-русски так попросту не говорят, но если бы это были не "балконы в квартире", а что-то более приемлемое, то по-английски использовались бы обороты 'there are', 'we have', 'can be found', (с натяжкой) 'are situated'. Мне английский тоже не родной, и о существовании `obtain (intransitive)` я до вчерашнего дня и не подозревал :) Но меня чем-то зацепило такое употребление, что, собственно, и сподвигло написать комментарий...

Comment: Мне стало интересно, а как бы native-English воспринял фразу `In my apartment two balconies obtain`. Это, должно быть, звучит очень забавно, что-то вроде "В моей квартире два балкона пребывают". :)

Comment: @tum_ exactly, that's part of the reason i used it, to parallel the awkwardness of the Russian находиться for the situation... btw you don't get banned for extensive comments, if they're off-topic the worst which can happen is they will be moved to chat

Comment: @tum_ Dmitry Grigoryev suggested a good equivalent of находиться - to be located

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both options are fine, except that one small grammar error has to be corrected:

> Два балкона находятся у нас в квартире.
>
> Два балкона находятся в наше**й** квартире.

As a native speaker, I would say simpler:

> У нас в квартире два балкона.
>
> Or: В нашей квартире два балкона.
>
> Or: У нас два балкона.

Answer (score 2):

Belonging is transitive so either form will do.

Answer (score 1):

"находиться" can be roughly translated as "to be located" or "to lie" (as in *London is located in England*), so it's an awkward word choice for your case. It would be a fine choice if you wanted to talk about the actual location of the balconies rather than the mere presence:

> С левой стороны находятся два балкона. - Two balconies are located on the left side.

In your case it's best to use a form of "иметь" (as in "Наша квартира имеет два балкона") or "быть" (e.g. "В нашей квартире [есть] два балкона).